# How can I delete vocabulary terms at a certain level?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, drush

I know there are several threads here about deleting terms with various techniques; I'm going to experiment deleting terms with drush at a certain level, say level three terms and below in the hierarchy. I was just curious if anyone here has any good ideas for this to inspire my work!

---

I'm pretty sure that can be done with the TermStorage class method loadAllParents, then determining which terms will be removed based on that count. I had forgotten about that method, loadParents would be much harder to use in this case, because we want to move all the way up the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Since my answer is being criticized for not being an answer (use loadAllParents and then perform the delete logic), I'll post some code, I guess that's what users want. This is untested and probably needs some more work, but this is basically what I meant

```
<?php

$manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term');

$vid = 'some_vocabulary_id';

$tree = $manager->loadTree($vid, $parent = 0, $max_depth = NULL, $load_entities = TRUE);

$result = [];

foreach ($tree as $term) {
  $parents = $manager->loadAllParents($term->id());
  if (count($parents) > 3) {
    $result[] = $term;
  }
}

foreach ($result as $item) {
  $manager->delete($item);
}
```